# FTP Adapter Oracle SOA

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel, oracle-soa, bpelxexec

I want to read file with the gap of 3mint each. So my BPEL FTP adapter read every file after 3mint. e.g. I have 5 files in a directory and my FTP adapter reads 1st file and after 3 mint he reads 2nd and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> - In BPEL FTP / File Adapter Configuration Wizard
> - In the Get File or Read Operation
> - Next to the file name slide
> - you can set "Polling Frequency" to  3 Minutes
> - so that it will poll for the file every 3 minutes
> - after that check the .jca file it has the below property

```
<property name="PollingFrequency" value="180"/>
```

> - from that you can edit the polling frequency

Comment: Thanks for your kind help but I got the solution. there is another property called MaxRaiseSize. How this property work,see the detail
------------------------
This property specifies the maximum number of files that the Oracle File or FTP Adapter submits for processing in each polling cycle. For example, if the inbound directory has 1000 files and MaxRaiseSize is set to 100 and the polling frequency is one minute, then the Oracle File or FTP Adapter will submit 100 files every minute.
------------------------

Comment: yes you are right if '<property name="PollingFrequency" value="180"/>' and '<property name="MaxRaiseSize" value="100"/>' for every polling cycle of 180 sec it processes 100 files. i think u r processing 1 file every 3 mnutes. so MaxRaiseSize = 1 or nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following property for your file adapter configuration

```
property name="PollingFrequency" value="180"   
property name="MaxRaiseSize" value="1"
```